# Difference between FetchRequest and ClaimsRequest

Tags: .net, openid, dotnetopenauth

As I understand both can be used to request, say, e-mail from OP. What's the difference and which one is preferred?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ClaimsRequest is intended to use the standard claims defined by OpenID (Simple Registration).

Use FetchRequest if you need to extend the claims provided by simple registration. For instance:

```
> var fr = new FetchRequest();
> fr.Attributes.AddRequired("DepartamentID");
> AuthenticationRequest.AddExtension(fr);
```